# 'InternalLinkedHashmap not a subtype' error when parsing Json Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using TypeAheadFormField to show suggestions to the user as they type, with data pulled from an API designed to autosuggest items.

I have isolated the issue and it is failing at the `suggestionsCallback:` stage, as the call is made. I have isolated it to the API call and the parsing of the data. I have tried lots of variations in the Class, call etc but can't get the error to go on running.

The error showing under text field(on simulator)

[image]

My Class (Made with Quicktype.io) I have tried lots of versions and none worked for me.

```
Items itemsFromJson(String str) => Items.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String itemsToJson(Items data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Items {
    Items({
        required this.items,
        required this.queryTerms,
    });

    List<Item>? items;
    List<dynamic>? queryTerms;
    
    factory Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Items(
        items: json["items"] == null ? null : List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
        queryTerms: json["queryTerms"] == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(json["queryTerms"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "items": items == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(items!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "queryTerms": queryTerms == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(queryTerms!.map((x) => x)),
    };
}

class Item {
    Item({
        required this.title,
        required this.id,
        required this.resultType,
        required this.address,
        required this.position,
        required this.access,
        required this.distance,
        required this.categories,
        required this.references,
        required this.highlights,
        required this.localityType,
        required this.mapView,
        required this.administrativeAreaType,
    });

    String? title;
    String? id;
    ResultType? resultType;
    ItemAddress? address;
    Position? position;
    List<Position>? access;
    int? distance;
    List<Category>? categories;
    List<Reference>? references;
    Highlights? highlights;
    String? localityType;
    MapView? mapView;
    String? administrativeAreaType;

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        resultType: json["resultType"] == null ? null : resultTypeValues.map![json["resultType"]],
        address: json["address"] == null ? null : ItemAddress.fromJson(json["address"]),
        position: json["position"] == null ? null : Position.fromJson(json["position"]),
        access: json["access"] == null ? null : List<Position>.from(json["access"].map((x) => Position.fromJson(x))),
        distance: json["distance"] == null ? null : json["distance"],
        categories: json["categories"] == null ? null : List<Category>.from(json["categories"].map((x) => Category.fromJson(x))),
        references: json["references"] == null ? null : List<Reference>.from(json["references"].map((x) => Reference.fromJson(x))),
        highlights: json["highlights"] == null ? null : Highlights.fromJson(json["highlights"]),
        localityType: json["localityType"] == null ? null : json["localityType"],
        mapView: json["mapView"] == null ? null : MapView.fromJson(json["mapView"]),
        administrativeAreaType: json["administrativeAreaType"] == null ? null : json["administrativeAreaType"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "resultType": resultType == null ? null : resultTypeValues.reverse![resultType],
        "address": address == null ? null : address!.toJson(),
        "position": position == null ? null : position!.toJson(),
        "access": access == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(access!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "distance": distance == null ? null : distance,
        "categories": categories == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(categories!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "references": references == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(references!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "highlights": highlights == null ? null : highlights!.toJson(),
        "localityType": localityType == null ? null : localityType,
        "mapView": mapView == null ? null : mapView!.toJson(),
        "administrativeAreaType": administrativeAreaType == null ? null : administrativeAreaType,
    };
}

class Position {
    Position({
        required this.lat,
        required this.lng,
    });

    double? lat;
    double? lng;

    factory Position.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Position(
        lat: json["lat"] == null ? null : json["lat"].toDouble(),
        lng: json["lng"] == null ? null : json["lng"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lat": lat == null ? null : lat,
        "lng": lng == null ? null : lng,
    };
}

class ItemAddress {
    ItemAddress({
        required this.label,
    });

    String? label;

    factory ItemAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ItemAddress(
        label: json["label"] == null ? null : json["label"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "label": label == null ? null : label,
    };
}

class Category {
    Category({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.primary,
    });

    String? id;
    String? name;
    bool? primary;

    factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        primary: json["primary"] == null ? null : json["primary"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "primary": primary == null ? null : primary,
    };
}

class Highlights {
    Highlights({
        required this.title,
        required this.address,
    });

    List<Title>? title;
    HighlightsAddress? address;

    factory Highlights.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Highlights(
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : List<Title>.from(json["title"].map((x) => Title.fromJson(x))),
        address: json["address"] == null ? null : HighlightsAddress.fromJson(json["address"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(title!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "address": address == null ? null : address!.toJson(),
    };
}

class HighlightsAddress {
    HighlightsAddress({
        required this.label,
    });

    List<Title>? label;

    factory HighlightsAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HighlightsAddress(
        label: json["label"] == null ? null : List<Title>.from(json["label"].map((x) => Title.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "label": label == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(label!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Title {
    Title({
        required this.start,
        required this.end,
    });

    int? start;
    int? end;

    factory Title.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Title(
        start: json["start"] == null ? null : json["start"],
        end: json["end"] == null ? null : json["end"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "start": start == null ? null : start,
        "end": end == null ? null : end,
    };
}

class MapView {
    MapView({
        required this.west,
        required this.south,
        required this.east,
        required this.north,
    });

    double? west;
    double? south;
    double? east;
    double? north;

    factory MapView.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MapView(
        west: json["west"] == null ? null : json["west"].toDouble(),
        south: json["south"] == null ? null : json["south"].toDouble(),
        east: json["east"] == null ? null : json["east"].toDouble(),
        north: json["north"] == null ? null : json["north"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "west": west == null ? null : west,
        "south": south == null ? null : south,
        "east": east == null ? null : east,
        "north": north == null ? null : north,
    };
}

class Reference {
    Reference({
        required this.supplier,
        required this.id,
    });

    Supplier? supplier;
    String? id;

    factory Reference.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Reference(
        supplier: json["supplier"] == null ? null : Supplier.fromJson(json["supplier"]),
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "supplier": supplier == null ? null : supplier!.toJson(),
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
    };
}

class Supplier {
    Supplier({
        required this.id,
    });

    String id;

    factory Supplier.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Supplier(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
    };
}

enum ResultType { PLACE, LOCALITY, ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA, STREET }

final resultTypeValues = EnumValues({
    "administrativeArea": ResultType.ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA,
    "locality": ResultType.LOCALITY,
    "place": ResultType.PLACE,
    "street": ResultType.STREET
});

class EnumValues<T> {
    Map<String, T>? map;
    Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

    EnumValues(this.map);

    Map<T, String>? get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
            reverseMap = map!.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap;
    }
}
```

My API call for the data

```
class UserApi {
  static FutureOr<Iterable<Item>> getUserSuggestions(String query) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https_call');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List users = json.decode(response.body);

      return users.map((json) => Item.fromJson(json)).where((user) {
        final nameLower = user.address!.label!.toLowerCase();
        final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();

        return nameLower.contains(queryLower);
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to put

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> users1 = json.decode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> users = users1["items"];
```

in place of

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List users = json.decode(response.body);
```